# Dynamically adding markers to Google maps

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to add markers to my Google map dynamically using a combination of ajax and php.
The first part of the code sends the latlng to the php file. The php file then returns the marker location needed.

When I alert the return part (ALERT TEST TO ENSURE PHP PROCESSED DATA CORRECTLY), it looks OK, but I cant seem to add the markers from the return on to my map.

See code below.
//SEND DATA TO URL (send to php file)
//RETURN DATA FOR PLACE MARKERS (this is what the return php file produces)

Many thanks,

//SEND DATA TO URL

```
     var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
     HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
     }}                     
     xmlHttp.open("POST",'MYPHPFILE',true);
     xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlHttp.send("LATLON="+strLAT);
```

//RETURN DATA FOR PLACE MARKERS

```
     var wxlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52,1); 
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
     position: wxlatlng,
     map: map,
     icon: '../../icons/flags/traffic_light_red.png',
     title: 'TEST', });
```

//RETURN DATA FOR PLACE MARKERS

```
     var wxlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52,1.1); 
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
     position: wxlatlng,
     map: map,
     icon: '../../icons/flags/traffic_light_red.png',
     title: 'TEST', });
```

//ALERT TEST TO ENSURE PHP PROCESSED DATA CORRECTLY

```
     function HandleResponse(response) {
            document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
            alert($('#ResponseDiv').text());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i found for my question was to use the php file to create the markers xml file and load the xml file via jQuery response

See code below;

```
 jQuery.get(YOURXMLFILE, function(data) {
       jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
       var eachMarker = jQuery(this);
       var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(
       parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Lat").text()),
       parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Lng").text())
       );
       var header  = eachMarker.find("title").text();
       var content = eachMarker.find("Content").text();
       var wxicon  = eachMarker.find("icon").text();
       //--------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerCoords,
        icon: wxicon,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: header,
        });
        });
        });
```